# VS Code IDE in English with Chinese Comments

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments, cjk

VS Code version: Code 1.45.0

We use contractors in China and they put some comments in Chinese. The characters are displayed as '?' due to decoding. I've added the Chinese Mandarin plugins for traditional and simple but this don't work. I need the IDE to be English but support Chinese in comments. Is this possible? Here's an example:
//180����ʱ��ɺ�60�룬60 seconds after 180 countdown is complete